# how can i get id/ generate id  of dynamically generated elements in html using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi i have a student profile form where student can fill their details.
Student can add school, add high school and add college dynamically by clicking add school, add high school and add college anchor tag.

[image: Student Profile]

Code for this form is as below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.studentprofileupdateBody a').click(function () {
                console.log('ok');
                var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').prev()
                var clone = $tr.clone();
                $tr.after(clone);
            });
        });
    </script>


<form method="post" action="">

    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td>
        <div id="Education">
                   <table class="Studentprofile" id="tblEducation">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/> Education Details</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="schoolRow" name="schoolRow">
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                                <label for="schools">Schools:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody" id="schools">
                                <input type="text" id="s1" name="s1" title="S1"></input>
                                <select name="selSYear">
                                    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                                    <option value="1">2010</option>
                                    <option value="2">2009</option>
                                    <option value="3">2008</option>
                                    <option value="4">2007</option>
                                    <option value="5">2006</option>
                                    <option value="6">2005</option>
                                    <option value="7">2004</option>
                                    <option value="8">2001</option>
                                    <option value="8">2000</option>
                                <//select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <a href="#">Add Schools</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><hr class="profileUpdate"/><br/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="highschoolRow" name="highschoolRow">
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                                <label for="highschool">High School:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody" id="highschool">
                                <input type="text" id="hs1" name="hs11" title="HS1" />
                                <select name="selHSYear">
                                    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                                    <option value="1">2010</option>
                                    <option value="2">2009</option>
                                    <option value="3">2008</option>
                                    <option value="4">2007</option>
                                    <option value="5">2006</option>
                                    <option value="6">2005</option>
                                    <option value="7">2004</option>
                                    <option value="8">2001</option>
                                    <option value="8">2000</option>
                                <//select>>
                                <br><br/>

                                <hr class="profileSubSection"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <a href="#">Add High Schools</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><hr class="profileUpdate"/><br/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="collegeRow" name="collegeRow">
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                                <label for="college">College:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody" id="college">
                                <input type="text" id="co1" name="co1" title="CO1"/>
                                <select name="selColYear">
                                    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                                    <option value="1">2010</option>
                                    <option value="2">2009</option>
                                    <option value="3">2008</option>
                                    <option value="4">2007</option>
                                    <option value="5">2006</option>
                                    <option value="6">2005</option>
                                    <option value="7">2004</option>
                                    <option value="8">2001</option>
                                    <option value="8">2000</option>
                                <//select>
                                <br><br/>

                                <hr class="profileSubSection"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <a href="#">Add College</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><hr class="profileUpdate"/><br/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <input type="submit" id="saveStudentEducationInfo" name="saveStudentEducationInfo" title="Save Education Info" value="Save Details" />
                                <input type="submit" id="cancelStudentEducationInfo" name="cancelStudentEducationInfo" title="Cancel Education Info" value="Cancel" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><br/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

It works perfect and add any no of elements dynamically but when i see the page source of this page i get to know that its not generating new elements id.

It looks like this..

[image]

Generated New elements but by viewing source code of this page it gives,

```
    <form method="post" action="">

    <table width="100%">

    <tr>
       <td>
        <div id="Education">
                   <table class="Studentprofile" id="tblEducation">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/> Education Details</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="schoolRow" name="schoolRow">

                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                                <label for="schools">Schools:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody" id="schools">
                                <input type="text" id="s1" name="s1" title="S1"></input>
                                <select name="selSYear">
                                    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                                    <option value="1">2010</option>

                                    <option value="2">2009</option>
                                    <option value="3">2008</option>
                                    <option value="4">2007</option>
                                    <option value="5">2006</option>
                                    <option value="6">2005</option>
                                    <option value="7">2004</option>

                                    <option value="8">2001</option>
                                    <option value="8">2000</option>
                                <//select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>

                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <a href="#">Add Schools</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><hr class="profileUpdate"/><br/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="highschoolRow" name="highschoolRow">

                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                                <label for="highschool">High School:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody" id="highschool">
                                <input type="text" id="hs1" name="hs11" title="HS1" />
                                <select name="selHSYear">
                                    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                                    <option value="1">2010</option>

                                    <option value="2">2009</option>
                                    <option value="3">2008</option>
                                    <option value="4">2007</option>
                                    <option value="5">2006</option>
                                    <option value="6">2005</option>
                                    <option value="7">2004</option>

                                    <option value="8">2001</option>
                                    <option value="8">2000</option>
                                <//select>>
                                <br><br/>

                                <hr class="profileSubSection"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <a href="#">Add High Schools</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><hr class="profileUpdate"/><br/></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr id="collegeRow" name="collegeRow">
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                                <label for="college">College:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody" id="college">
                                <input type="text" id="co1" name="co1" title="CO1"/>
                                <select name="selColYear">

                                    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                                    <option value="1">2010</option>
                                    <option value="2">2009</option>
                                    <option value="3">2008</option>
                                    <option value="4">2007</option>
                                    <option value="5">2006</option>

                                    <option value="6">2005</option>
                                    <option value="7">2004</option>
                                    <option value="8">2001</option>
                                    <option value="8">2000</option>
                                <//select>
                                <br><br/>

                                <hr class="profileSubSection"/>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <a href="#">Add College</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><hr class="profileUpdate"/><br/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateHead" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="studentprofileupdateBody">
                                <input type="submit" id="saveStudentEducationInfo" name="saveStudentEducationInfo" title="Save Education Info" value="Save Details" />

                                <input type="submit" id="cancelStudentEducationInfo" name="cancelStudentEducationInfo" title="Cancel Education Info" value="Cancel" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><br/><br/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

I want my code to generate new id for each element to distinctly identify each element by its id.

How can i get id for each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method, add thats copy everything...
You can modify the id where are using that methor, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.studentprofileupdateBody a').click(function () {
        console.log('ok');
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
        var clone = $tr.clone().attr("id","new-id");
        $tr.after(clone);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** To have dynamic id for each row('input' and 'tr'), you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dynamicId, inputName, numberEachType;
    $('.studentprofileupdateBody a').click(function () {
        console.log('ok');
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
        numberEachType = $('table#tblEducation tr[name="'+$tr.attr('name')+'"]').length;
        dynamicId = $tr.attr('name') + numberEachType;
        var clone = $tr.clone().attr('id',dynamicId); //dynamic ID at <tr>
        inputName = clone.find('input').attr('name');
        dynamicId = inputName.substring(0,inputName.length-1) + (numberEachType+1);
        clone.find('input').attr('id',dynamicId).attr('name',dynamicId).attr('title',dynamicId.toUpperCase()); //dynamic ID, Name and title at <input>
        $tr.after(clone);
    });
});
```

Try an example here [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/NT4Zr/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/NT4Zr/2/) and see the source code, if it's this what you want.

Comment: @ expertCode: by viewing source code i found that its not generated new id. is there any other alternative to do so??

Comment: @Bhargav but which 'id' you're referring? the <tr> or the <input> ?

Comment: @ expertCode: I want to save all inputs to the database. For this purpose i want id of all newly generated elements. Like i have 5 text boxes in my form <input type="text" id="t1" /> <input type="text" id="t2" /> and so on.. by using above jquery it will created new elements but by viewing its source only parent details are shown but i want details of all elements. how can i do so?

Comment: I made update in my post (and jsfiddle link too). See and confirm if it's that what you want ;)

Comment: @ expertCode:Thanks for your new post. Its working fine. but its not going to show me in page source. On mouse over its showing me the id, as per your new code. anyways thanks for support. i will look in to this and try to solve this...

Comment: @Bhargav i didn't understand again you doubt. All id's are created dynamically, if you see the page source you proves that.

Comment: I have updated code like this for delete element but not working pls chk it. http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/5/     Instead of writing jquery i have written <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" /> it will delete the element. But it also deletes first parent on click on delete button. how can i overcome from this issue?

Comment: You are adding new rows dynamicly, so you need to use [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method instead [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method. See my update at you code [http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/30/].

Comment: sorry try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/30/](http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/30/). Relative of you mainly and first post question, you solved it with my answers?

Comment: Yes its working... your answer is helpful to me, but i am stuck on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634001/how-can-i-add-textbox-value-entered-by-user-to-label-dynamically-using-jquery . help me to find out something related to this. or give me some hints.